# How do I run a model inside a Magento controller?

Tags: magento

Here's my controller.

```
public function mockcron_newmatchAction(){
    $task = Mage::getModel('showdown/cron::makematch');
    var_dump($task);
}
```

And here's the cron function located at `app/code/local/Desbest/Showdown/Model`

```
<?php
class Desbest_Showdown_Model_Cron
{
    public function makematch(){
        $var = "apples";
        return $var;
    }
}
```

The problem is that `$task = Mage::getModel('showdown/cron::makematch');` does not run and I want that model to run. What do I do?

The variable prints as `false`, regardless of whether I have chosen an existing model or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `::` syntax only works if you're providing a source model in a `system.xml` XML.

```
ex. 
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/etc/system.xml
<source_model>paypal/config::getApiAuthenticationMethods</source_model>
```

It doesn't work when you're writing regular PHP code.  The syntax you want is

```
$task = Mage::getModel('showdown/cron')->makematch();
```

The call to `Mage::getModel('showdown/cron')` instantiates your model object, and then the `->makematch();` calls a method, as per standard PHP. When you say

```
Mage::getModel('showdown/cron::makematch');
```

you're asking magento to instantiate the class with an alias of `showdown/cron::makematch`.  Since that's an invalid alias alias, this will always return false.